# How to access generated Javascript (ScriptObject) from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that generates a lot of Google Maps objects on the Silverlight site. For example a Map is created like this:

```
var map = HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance(@"google.maps.Map", container, mapOptions);
var center = (ScriptObject)_map.Invoke("getCenter");
```

Everything works fine. But now I need to access the map object from Javascript directly. I think it could be done by exposing a map property as ScriptableMember and use it from Javascript. But that"s a bit odd because the map object lives already in the browser. But how do I access it?

Update

Just to make clearer what I'm talking about

Let's say I have created my map as shown above. Now I have a loaded Javasript file with this function:

```
function ReadMapCenter()
{
  //Need the map object in Javascript
  map.getCenter();
}
```

How can I access the existing map Object from Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just expose it as type `ScriptObject` I think the bridge will simply unpack the scripted object rather than create yet another layer of wrapping for it.

**Alternative**

Don't use `CreateInstance`

In your javascript at the global leve use:-

```
var map;
function createMap(container, mapOptions)
{
     if (!map)
     {
        map = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
     }
     return map;
}
```

now your javascript has a `map` global it can use.

In silverlight use:-

```
 var map = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("createMap", container, mapOptions);
```

Comment: Added some more explanation to my initial post. Not sure if it was clear what I'm talking about.

Comment: That's right. I was not thinking about that. I was caputured in the SL world and thought there must be a way to gt the ScriptObject. Like this I have to change a few things but it might be the easiest way. Thanks for the pointer.